# IIS Url rewrite rule for Angular SPA + WebApi

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a SPA + WebAPI application, they are both in the same project. I only want the WebAPI application to process requests from the directory "api". So anything under api will be handled by the server, everything else will be handled by the Angular SPA.

I currently have

```
   <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This works OK except when I go to the URL

`http://localhost/customers/2` (which loads the doc but all resources are coming in with the wrong mime type I have concluded its because of the redirect rules above)

the URL `http://localhost/customers` works fine will be routed by my SPA app

How do I get everything to be redirected to my SPA except for the requests that come under the API directory?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to solve this ? Running into exactly the same predicament

Answer (score 14):

I do this with two rules. One to "whitelist" the server-side controllers I want to go to asp.net, which includes /api but also the authentication stuff under /Account and /Manage. The next sends everything else to angular unless it's a file or folder, much like what you already have.

```
    <rule name="API Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(api|account|manage)(.*)$" />
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Angular Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
```

Try it this way, but feel free to remove "|account|manage" if you don't want those requests going to the server.

To see my entire ruleset, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33986338/angular-spa-on-iis-with-url-rewriting-404s-load-angular-infinitely) I have posted, where I handle HTTPS and canonical hostnames as well.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for posting your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Update this line

```
<match url=".*" />
```

To this

```
<match url=".*|.*/.*$" />
```

Comment: And this does not work.. The API routes still work but the SPA routing just doesnt get trigerred